# How to enable and disable an Actionbutton in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny app. I am facing an issue. I am having an actionButton. The button should be enabled only when certain details are filled.For instance, the button should be enabled only when the value in TextOutput is 100 exactly.If not, button should be disabled.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
#install.packages("shinyjs")

ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(),
                inlineCSS(list('.lightpink' = "background-color: lightpink",'.red'   = "background-color: red", "textarea" = 'text-align: center', '#text3 ' = 'text-align: center')),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
                  ),
                  column(3, actionButton("submit", "Complete"))
                ),
                fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
                fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3")))),
                tags$style(type = 'text/css', "#submit {display:inline-block; width:75%;margin-top: 25px}")

)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{ input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count),
                                                             function(i) {
                                                               inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
                                                               textInputRow <- function (inputId,value) {
                                                                 textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal" )
                                                                 #numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
                                                               }
                                                               column(4,textInputRow(inputName, "")) })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})



  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("id",lim)]], { 
        updateTextAreaInput(session,paste0("id",lim), value = ({
          x =  as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]])
          if(!(is.numeric(x))){0}
          else if(!(is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            if(x < 0){
              0 
            }else if(x > 100){
              100
            } else{
              return (isolate(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
            } 
          } 
          #else{0}
          else if((is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            0
          } 
        })
        )
      })
      req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) >= 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <= 100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({
    #getvalues()
    # if(getvalues() > 100){
    #    0



    # }
    #else(getvalues())

    getvalues()

  })

  observeEvent(getvalues(), {
    nn <- getvalues()
    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      removeClass("text3", 'red')
      addClass('text3','lightpink')

    } else  { addClass('text3','red')}
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

This is the code used. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: `shinyjs::disable()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `toggleState` or `enable` / `disable` combination inside your `observeEvent`

```
observeEvent(getvalues(), {

    nn <- getvalues()

    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      disable("View")
      removeClass("text3", "red")
      addClass("text3","lightpink")          

    } else  { 

      enable("View")
      addClass("text3","red")

    }

})
```

[image]